# Android background process equivalent to ios appdelegate

Tags: android, android-service

I am doing  background process in my android application for that i used service.In iphone i use appdelegate for the background process.

My question is any other alternate methods to do the background process in andorid? If so which will be the best one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To perform background process in Android you have 3 best options:

1) [Thread](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/timer-thread-example-in-android-programming/)

2) [Service](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

3) [ASYCN task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)

All these three are for the same purpose for which you are looking.

**To stop Thread:**

In general, you don't forcibly stop **threads because it's dangerous**. You set a flag that tells the thread in question to exit from it's thread loop under controlled circumstances.

Your thread loop looks something along these lines:

```
void run() {
  while (shouldContinue) {
    doThreadWorkUnit();
  }
}
```

[How to Stop Thread:](http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html)

Comment: Now Service is my first option to do my work.Because i am doing server listening process when application is running.am i correct?

Comment: yaah, sure you can do that with service....even Thread is also a good option for this...As generally I use thread...!!!

Comment: How to do background process with thread? When we interact with user interface the app will display ANR?

Comment: When i want to moves out from server listening process for that i need to stop thread.How can i do that?